# LinearLayout: layout_width vs. minWidth

Tags: android

I'm trying to have a layout in a certain width, using the `layout_width` property, but when inflated - the width of the layout is taken from the child, which is smaller then the `layout_width` I stated. Here's an example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/blabla"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="310dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:paddingTop="15dip"
    android:paddingLeft="23dip"
    android:text="udini "
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

This code make the entire layout be in the width of `60dip`.
But when adding the `minWidth` attribute to the layout, with the value `310dip`, then the width of the layout is as expected.

**Why is it like that? Is the `layout_width` attribute just a suggestion?**

Thanks,

Udi

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`LinearLayout`s are not required to honour the `layout_width` attribute when it's not set to `wrap_content` or `fill_parent`.

You can still use `android:minWidth` if that's enough for you, or other options are using the `android:layout_weight` attribute or increase the `android:padding` attribute on the child.

Comment: Is that information written anywhere? Because the android's documentation claims that both fixed value and fill_parent/wrap_content suppose to work.

Comment: Yes, it is somewhere, I was trying to find it when I wrote the answer, but I couldn't :/ Anyways, re-reading the question, why don't you just set the width of the TextView to 310dip (or 310-padding)?

Comment: Well...I had a reason, I can't remember why, but that should work I think..
Thanks for the info