# TextView not honoring minWidth in LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view

[image]Use Case :

### This is how my View should look

TextView1|TextView2| ImageView

When text on TextView1 is Long , it shrinks TextView2 untill it gets  invisble for very long text:

I also cant set weights to the textviews as this will create empty space between TextView1 and TextView2 when textview1 is not long ebough . I want them both to be stuck with each other

Problem Statement : TextView1 should fill all the available space but TextView2 not shrink

My approach:

```
<LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id="@+id/thumbnail_footer_details"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:paddingEnd="@dimen/footer_padding_left"
               android:paddingTop="@dimen/footer_detail_margin_top"
               android:paddingBottom="@dimen/footer_padding_bottom"
               android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/asset_details"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/asset_item_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/detail_tile_color"
                      android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/footer_padding_left"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/item_description"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:minWidth="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/footer_padding_left"

                        android:maxLines="1"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
                <ImageView
                    style="@style/ImageViewStyle"
                    android:background="@drawable/thumbnail_options"/>
           </LinearLayout>
```

I have tried giving TextView 2(id- item_description) a minimum width but it is not honored. Can someone help me with it ?

PS: There is an ImageView above this LinearLayout

Comment: Where did you specify the minimum with?

Comment: in TextView 2 (id-> item_description). I tried but it didn't work so i removed it.

Comment: If you don't show us what you tried, we have no idea of knowing what you tried. Show what you tried

Comment: @ChrisNeve I have updated the Layout with minWidth attribute.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693021/linearlayout-layout-width-vs-minwidth

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- set the width at runtime, or
- use `ConstraintLayout` instead

Here's the implementation using `ConstraintLayout` approach. Having defined following `xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some really really really really long long long long long long long long long long long text"
        android:background="#ffaadd"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#aaffc4"
        android:text="TextView 2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView 3"
        android:background="#ffd0aa"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is what you'll get on output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't set the width at run time . Let me try the Constraint Layout solution . But I am still not able to comprehend why TextView2 will not honor minWidth